# Reusing github actions workflow

Tags: workflow, github-actions

Here I want to create branch deployment pipeline. Deployment will be done on every pull request and we need to get a branch name, so that we call a workflow with that branch name. I have tried to do it in the following way, But it is giving an error.

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
env:
  WORKFLOW: 'bigelio/todo/.github/workflows/branch-deployment-serverless-deploy.yml@${{ github.head_ref }}'

deploy:
    needs: [terraform]

    uses: $WORKFLOW
    secrets:
      TF_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TF_API_TOKEN }}
```

The error I am getting in github is this

```
    Invalid workflow file: .github/workflows/branch-deployment-workflow.yml#L198
invalid value workflow reference: no version specified
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `env` context is available on a runner, while `uses` is evaluated outside that context, before runner is scheduled/created.

You can try using `gh` cli with something like: `gh workflow run triage.yml --ref my-branch`.

Alternatively, you could see if [Environments](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment) would suite your needs.